# Xcode 4.5 - crash log not symbolicated

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

A user emailed me a crash log for an app I submitted to the App Store.  I have the original app store submission archive in Xcode still, but his crash report will not symbolicate.  Clicking "resymbolicate" doesn't do anything.  I can't find the symbolicatecrash script using mdfind, is it still a part of Xcode 4.5?  Is there any way to symbolicate this crash log?

Comment: what happens if you just place the dsym and hte log in on folder, and then try to open the crash log?

Comment: That worked - sort of.  It did symbolicate the one line from my app that was causing the problem, so that's helpful, but it didn't show the stuff from the OS.  Still, it's enough to go on for now.  So thanks!  You should change your comment to an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I have been having issues with partial symbolication, after Xcode 4.5 came out. I am not sure if its a bug with the symbolication process, or if its still not the correct way to symbolicated the crash logs. Glad you caught the trouble maker in your crash log!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the dsym and the log in one folder, and then try to open the crash log.

Comment: This does not work for me. What exactly do you put together along with the .crash file? 
dSYMs package? 
appname.app.dSYM package?
Ssome other file on this packages?

Comment: Ok i Fixed, i just went to the xarchive folder and run this command line: mdimport .

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't already tried this, upgrade your mac to OSX 10.8.2 or newer. I *was* running OSX 10.7.5, and upgrading **immediately** fixed my sybolication woes.

I had tried pretty much **everything** to get my crash logs to symbolicate. I never had problems before, but a few months had passed since I'd looked at a crash log; at some point during that period I upgraded to Xcode 4.5.2. It seems to me that something with the Xcode 4.5.2 symbolicatecrash perl script does not work correctly on a mac running OSX 10.7.5. In symbolicatecrash, it calls atos to symbolicate an address; it couldn't find the matching symbols, even though I **knew for a fact** that I had the correct xcarchive. Anyhow, spring for OSX 10.8.2 or newer and hopefully that'll work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me was:

To go to the xarchive folder with terminal. 
Run: `mdimport .`

And xcode can now re-symbolicate properly.
The problem is that spotlight is not indexing the archives folder for some stupid reason (lion 10.7)!